# Animated Int to Int change in Vue.js with watcher

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I regularly receive each 2000ms a new value from an event listener.

Once new value is received, I want to immediately fire an animation to increment or decrement from previous value to a new value.

```
<script>
import { animateIntToInt } from './helpers'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      speed: {
        currentvalue: 0
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    speed () => // code to receive a speed value
  },

  watch: {
    speed (to, from) {
      this.speed = animateIntToInt(from.currentvalue, to.currentvalue, 1000)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And here is the animation helper code:

```
export function animateIntToInt (from, to, duration) {
  let current = from
  let difference = to - from
  // Calculate the interval for loops
  let interval = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / difference))
  // Determine direction to negative or positive
  let step = to > from ? 1 : -1

  let timer = setInterval(() => {
    current += step

    if (current === to) {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }

    return current
  }, interval)
}
```

I receive `undefined` value each time. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: `animateIntToInt` does not return anything.

Comment: really ? thank you, I didn't noticed that at all...

Comment: You are setting speed in your speed watcher.  Also speed is computed and should not be manually set.

Comment: I need to update this value in a hardcode-way, before having received a new value. Without using a query selection approach

Comment: Rewrite your animate function to accept a callback with the speed, and then update a speed property. No need for computed or watcher.  Or have it return a promise.  Where is your event listener?

Comment: @aspirinemaga When I say that it does not return anything, I don't mean that your function returns "undefined", but that it cannot return anything because you have no `return` statement in the function's block. the only `return` statement is inside the `setInterval` callback, making it useless.